# How to synchronize ranges only when the user stops panning and zooming?

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, synchronization, bokeh

I have many plots and many samples per plot. I need to zoom and pan in all plots. Also, all ranges must be synchronized in real time. If I share range works well with a few plots, but with many plots it becomes laggy. Then, to solve this I would like to trigger the synchronization just when the pan or zoom action finishes.

There is a `PanEnd` event which is triggered when the the user stops panning. But I cannot do the same with the wheel zoom because there is no a `MouseWheelEnd` event, just a `MouseWheel` event, so I cannot detect when the user stops. Finally I added a periodic callback to update the ranges from time to time. But I do not like this solution.

I have also tried `LODStart` and LODEnd events (related with downsampling) and I had to force `lod_threshold=1`. But sometimes `LODEnd` is not triggered, only `LODStart` is always triggered.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource, CDSView
from bokeh.models.filters import IndexFilter
from bokeh.models.markers import Scatter, Circle
from bokeh.models.tools import LassoSelectTool
from bokeh.models.ranges import DataRange1d
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, gridplot
from bokeh.events import MouseWheel, PanEnd
import numpy as np

N = 3500
x = np.random.random(size=N) * 200
y = np.random.random(size=N) * 200
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plots = []
x_ranges = []
y_ranges = []
p_last_modified = -1
def render_plot(i, p_last_modified):
    range_padding = 0.25
    x_range = DataRange1d(
        range_padding=range_padding,
        renderers=[]
    )
    y_range = DataRange1d(
        range_padding=range_padding,
        renderers=[]
    )

    plot = figure(
        width=500,
        height=500,
        x_range=x_range,
        y_range=y_range,
        toolbar_location='left',
        tools='pan,wheel_zoom,tap,lasso_select',
        output_backend='webgl',
    )
    c = plot.scatter(
        x='x',
        y='y',
        size=3,
        fill_color='blue',
        line_color=None,
        line_alpha=1.0,
        source=source,

        nonselection_fill_color='blue',
        nonselection_line_color=None,
        nonselection_fill_alpha=1.0,
    )
    c.selection_glyph = Scatter(
        fill_color='yellow',
        line_color='red',
        line_alpha=1.0,
    )

    def mouse_wheel_event(event):
        print('>> MOUSE WHEEL EVENT: PLOT NUMBER: {}'.format(i))
        global p_last_modified
        p_last_modified = i

    plot.on_event(MouseWheel, mouse_wheel_event)

    def pan_end_event(event):
        print('>> PAN END: {}'.format(i))
        for p in range(len(plots)):
            if p != i:
                plots[p].x_range.end = plots[i].x_range.end
                plots[p].x_range.start = plots[i].x_range.start
                plots[p].y_range.end = plots[i].y_range.end
                plots[p].y_range.start = plots[i].y_range.start

    plot.on_event(PanEnd, pan_end_event)

    plots.append(plot)
    x_ranges.append(x_range)
    y_ranges.append(y_range)

for i in range(12):
    render_plot(i, p_last_modified)

gp = gridplot(
    children=plots,
    ncols=4,
    plot_width=300,
    plot_height=300,
    toolbar_location='left',
)

def callback():
    global p_last_modified
    print('-- CALLBACK: last_modified: {}'.format(p_last_modified))
    if p_last_modified != -1:
        for p in range(len(plots)):
            if p != p_last_modified:
                plots[p].x_range.end = plots[p_last_modified].x_range.end
                plots[p].x_range.start = plots[p_last_modified].x_range.start
                plots[p].y_range.end = plots[p_last_modified].y_range.end
                plots[p].y_range.start = plots[p_last_modified].y_range.start
        p_last_modified = -1

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(callback, 3000)

curdoc().add_root(gp)
```

Any other suggestion?

Comment: there is no mousewheelend event because the wheel turns in increments, unlike holding a click which is continuous. There is no built-in even in JS, typically in JS you'd look for how much time has passed since the last event and if it's more than a given threshold you have your stop event.

Comment: Thanks @Seb, you think that the best approach is something like my code? A setTimeout function could work as well

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, although I don't like it so much.
It involves some JS and 3 'dummy' widgets, I'd expect there to be a more simple way, but anyhow that is one way.

`dum_txt_timer` is a textinput that will be used as a timer, its value is in seconds and will be updated with a desired timestep. When the value reaches a desired threshold the update on the ranges will be triggered. When the value is below the threshold it does nothing

`dum_button` is a button which does two things, a first click will start the timer in `dum_txt_timer`, a second click will stop the timer.

`dum_txt_trigger` is another textinput that is used to click `dum_button` and start/stop the timer.

The `mouse_wheel_event` function triggers on every single iteration of the mouse wheel. The value of the plot in which the mouse is is stored in `mod_source`, a data source that is passed to the `dum_txt_timer` callback.
It checks if the `dum_txt_timer` value is 0, if it is it updates the value in `dum_txt_trigger`, which clicks the button and starts the timer, and it updates dum_txt_timer so that other wheel events do nothing until the update. If it is different from 0 it does nothing.

The callback of the `dum_txt_timer` needs the `dum_txt_trigger`, the `mod_source` datasource that stores the plot ID and all the plot ranges.
The callback does nothing until the `dum_txt_timer` value is updated at the end of the timeout function. Otherwise it first updates the value of `dum_txt_trigger` which clicks `dum_button` a second time and stops the timer (resets it to 0. Then it updates the range of all the plots.

I this example the time before the update is set by the timeout function in the button callback.

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CDSView, IndexFilter, Scatter, Circle, LassoSelectTool, DataRange1d, CustomJS, TextInput, Button
from bokeh.events import MouseWheel, PanEnd
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, gridplot
import numpy as np

N = 3500
x = np.random.random(size=N) * 200
y = np.random.random(size=N) * 200
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

dum_txt_timer = TextInput(value='0',visible=False)

# javascript code for a dummy (invisible) button, it starts and stops a timer that will be written in dum_txt_timer
dum_button_code = """
if (cb_obj.button_type.includes('success')){
// start a timer in dum_txt by updating its value with a fixed timestep
var start = new Date(); 
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){var current = new Date(); var diff=((current-start)/1000.0).toFixed(4); dum_txt_timer.value=diff.toString();  }, 500)
cb_obj.button_type = 'warning';
} else {
// stop the timer and set the dum_txt_timer value back to 0
var noIntervals = setInterval(function(){});
for (var i = 0; i<noIntervals; i++) { window.clearInterval(i);}
dum_txt_timer.value='0';
cb_obj.button_type = 'success';
}
"""
dum_button = Button(label='dummy_button',button_type='success',visible=False) # the dummy button itself
dum_button.callback = CustomJS(args={'dum_txt_timer':dum_txt_timer},code=dum_button_code) # the callback of the button

# dummy textinput to click the dummy button
dum_txt_trigger = TextInput(value='0',visible=False)
dum_txt_trigger_code = """
// click the dummy button
var button_list = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for(var i=0;i<button_list.length;i++){
    if(button_list[i].textContent==="dummy_button"){button_list[i].click()}
}   
"""
dum_txt_trigger.js_on_change('value',CustomJS(code=dum_txt_trigger_code))

dum_box = widgetbox(dum_txt_timer,dum_txt_trigger,dum_button,visible=False)

plots = []
x_ranges = []
y_ranges = []
mod_source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x':[]})
reference = None
def render_plot(i):
    range_padding = 0.25
    x_range = DataRange1d(range_padding=range_padding,renderers=[])
    y_range = DataRange1d(range_padding=range_padding,renderers=[])

    plot = figure(width=500,height=500,x_range=x_range,y_range=y_range,toolbar_location='left',tools='pan,wheel_zoom,tap,lasso_select',output_backend='webgl',)
    c = plot.scatter(x='x',y='y',size=3,fill_color='blue',line_color=None,line_alpha=1.0,source=source,nonselection_fill_color='blue',nonselection_line_color=None,nonselection_fill_alpha=1.0,)
    c.selection_glyph = Scatter(fill_color='yellow',line_color='red',line_alpha=1.0,)

    def mouse_wheel_event(event):        

        if dum_txt_timer.value != '0': 
            return

        # if the timer value is 0, start the timer    
        dum_txt_trigger.value =  str(int(dum_txt_trigger.value)+1)
        dum_txt_timer.value = '0.0001' # immediatly update the timer value for the check on 0 in the python callback to work immediatly

        mod_source.data.update({'x':[i]})

    plot.on_event(MouseWheel, mouse_wheel_event)

    def pan_end_event(event):
        print('>> PAN END: {}'.format(i))
        for p in range(len(plots)):
            if p != i:
                plots[p].x_range.end = plots[i].x_range.end
                plots[p].x_range.start = plots[i].x_range.start
                plots[p].y_range.end = plots[i].y_range.end
                plots[p].y_range.start = plots[i].y_range.start

    plot.on_event(PanEnd, pan_end_event)

    plots.append(plot)
    x_ranges.append(x_range)
    y_ranges.append(y_range)

for i in range(12):
    render_plot(i)

dum_txt_timer_args = {'dum_txt_trigger':dum_txt_trigger,'mod_source':mod_source}
dum_txt_timer_args.update( {'xrange{}'.format(i):plot.x_range for i,plot in enumerate(plots)} )
dum_txt_timer_args.update( {'yrange{}'.format(i):plot.y_range for i,plot in enumerate(plots)} )

set_arg_list = "var xrange_list = [{}];".format(','.join(['xrange{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(plots))]))
set_arg_list += "var yrange_list = [{}];".format(','.join(['yrange{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(plots))]))

# code that triggers when the dum_txt_timer value is changed, so every 100 ms, but only clicks dum_button when the value is greater than 2 (seconds)
dum_txt_timer_code = set_arg_list + """
var timer = Number(cb_obj.value);
var trigger_val = Number(dum_txt_trigger.value);

// only do something when the value is greater than 2 (seconds)
if (timer>0.0001) {
    trigger_val = trigger_val + 1;
    dum_txt_trigger.value = trigger_val.toString(); // click button again to stop the timer

    // update the plot ranges
    var p_last_modified = mod_source.data['x'][0];
    var nplots = xrange_list.length;

    for (var i=0; i<nplots; i++){
        if (i!=p_last_modified){
            xrange_list[i].start = xrange_list[p_last_modified].start;
            xrange_list[i].end = xrange_list[p_last_modified].end;
            yrange_list[i].start = yrange_list[p_last_modified].start;
            yrange_list[i].end = yrange_list[p_last_modified].end;
        }
    }
}
"""

dum_txt_timer.js_on_change('value',CustomJS(args=dum_txt_timer_args,code=dum_txt_timer_code))

gp = gridplot(children=plots,ncols=4,plot_width=300,plot_height=300,toolbar_location='left',)

grid = gridplot([[gp],[dum_box]],toolbar_location=None)

curdoc().add_root(grid)
```

One nice thing is that the same dummy widgets can be used to set a delay on range updates from different events, the event callback just needs to update `dum_txt_trigger` like in `mouse_wheel_event`

Comment: Thank you for devoting your precious time. I was checking if your example works well. Sometimes I see that the rest of plot ranges are not synchronized at all after zooming with the wheel. Also, the downsampling is triggered but frequently it becomes stuck and samples do not back to the normal behaviour. Do you experience the same?

Comment: Yes I saw it not updating but it it fixed by another tiny wheel movement and do not happen often. I think it could be improved by using a longer timestep for the timer and setting the threshold to 1 step so the timer callback dont get executed too often

Comment: @ChesuCR i updated with a more robust version that just does one longer timestep. Note that it doesnt actually get 'stuck' it's just that sometime the points of the plot you zoom in keep their light shade even though the range update worked.

Comment: Uhmm now works okay, whough I notice a small laggy behaviour when zooming with the wheel. Anyway thanks for your hacky soulution !! I upvoted your answer